# Slides are not displayed in ionic4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I’m migrating source code from ionic3 to ionic4.
The following slide page is not displayed in ionic4.
How do I fix it?
I hope you would tell me.

(additional info)
I think, This seems to have a problem with the style, and it appears somewhere else.
So, I will also add information to SCSS.
Why can't I use the ionic3 style as it is in ionic4?

(more info)
If I comment out all walkthrough.page.scss, the image will appear in a part of the modal.
[Current status of the target screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XrXG.png)

**app.component.ts (The calling page)**

```
    ...
async error => {

const walkthroughModal = await this.modalCtrl.create({component: WalkthroughPage, componentProps:{prev_page: 'login'} });
    await walkthroughModal.present();
}
    ...
```

**walkthrough.page.ts**

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'page-walkthrough',
        templateUrl: 'walkthrough.page.html',
        styleUrls: ['walkthrough.page.scss'],
        providers: [CustomNativeStorage]
    })
    export class WalkthroughPage {
    ...

    @ViewChild('slides', {static: false}) slides: IonSlides;
...
```

**walkthrough.page.html**

```
<ion-slides pager="true">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of walkthroughSlides" [style.background-image]="slide.img">
        <div class="walkthrough-content-card">
            <div class="text-container">
                <div class="walkthrough-title">
                    {{ slide.title }}
                </div>
                <div class="walkthough-text">
                    {{ slide.text }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container">
                <ion-button class="button_continue" color="bright" (click)="slideNext()">
                    CONTINUE
                </ion-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

**walkthrough.page.scss**

```
$iphone4: "(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px)";
$iphone5: "(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px)";
$iphone6_7: "(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px)";

.ios, 
.md {

    .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active{
      width: 100% !important;
     }

    ion-slide {
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: top center;
    }

    .walkthrough-content-card{
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0px;
    }

    .text-container{        
        padding: 5%;
      .walkthrough-title{
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .walkthough-text{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
      }
    }

    .button-container{
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 15px;

      .button_continue{
        min-width: 50%;
        @extend .remove-text-transform,
        .remove-button-curves !optional;
      }
    }
}

.swiper-pagination-fraction, .swiper-pagination-custom,
 .swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets{
  bottom: 10%;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
  background: #FF9800;
}
.slide-zoom{
  height: 100% !important;
}


@media #{$iphone4}{
    .swiper-pagination-fraction, .swiper-pagination-custom,
     .swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets{
  bottom: 14.5% !important;
}
}
@media #{$iphone5}{
    .swiper-pagination-fraction, .swiper-pagination-custom, 
    .swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets{
  bottom: 11.5% !important;
}
}
@media #{$iphone6_7}{
    .swiper-pagination-fraction, .swiper-pagination-custom, 
    .swiper-container-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets{
  bottom: 10% !important;
}
}
```

**global.scss**

```
/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/core.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/structure.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/typography.css";
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/display.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/padding.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css";

//Universal Styles
.ios .japanese-fonts {
  font-family: "Hiragino Sans", "HiraKakuProN", sans-serif !important;
}

.md .japanese-fonts {
  font-family: "Noto Sans CJK", "モトヤフォント", sans-serif !important;
}

.ios,
.md {

  body {
    padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
    padding-right: constant(safe-area-inset-right);
    padding-bottom: constant(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    padding-left: constant(safe-area-inset-left);
    padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
    padding-right: env(safe-area-inset-right);
    padding-bottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
    padding-left: env(safe-area-inset-left);
  }

  .title-center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 90px 1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .back-button-style {
    z-index: 10;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }

  .remove-button-curves {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }

  .remove-text-transform {
    text-transform: none;
  }

  .remove-box-shadow {
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .explanation-text {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    color: var(--ion-color-text_gray);
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar,
  *::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }

  .tabs-md[tabsHighlight="true"] .tab-highlight {
    background-color: #4FC3F7 !important;
  }

  .tab-badge {
    background-color: #FF4141 !important;
  }

  .loading-wrapper {
    background: transparent !important;
    position: relative !important;
    bottom: 10%;
  }

  ion-backdrop {
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
  }

  .custom-spinner-box {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .loading-wrapper {
    color: white !important;
  }

  .custom-spinner-font {
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the walkthroughSlides data

Comment: i can help. but what is query?

Comment: I want to display the slide page (walkthrough.page.html) of the above source code, but it does not work.

Comment: i think issue with css style issue. can you try with comment all your css style and run

Answer (score 0):

When using `ViewChild` to monitor changes, you'll need to connect the slides variable you declare in your .ts file by adding a template reference to it on the ion-slides element like so:

```
<ion-slides pager="true" #slides>
// the slides
</ion-slides>
```

Checkout [The ViewChild Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) for more info.

Comment: Tnak you for your reply. But It's not work. It just displays a white modal.

Comment: The cause seems to be CSS. It seems that the style of ionic3 is useless. what should I do.

Comment: Ahh, in that case I believe the error lies in that you've declared specific styles to override the class names Ionic generates, but you need to put these styles within the global variables.scss file for them to take effect. Can you give that a try?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm happy because I'm so troubled. 
Should I move a specific style from walkthrough.page.scss to global.scss ? 
I also added global.scss to the above question body.

Comment: In my experience, I've needed to move any class names that were Ionic specific to global.scss. For instance, you should be able to style using the `ion-slide` selector and Ionic's provided CSS custom options (see [this page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides#css-custom-properties)) from your local .scss file, but will need to move things like `.swiper-pagination-bullet-active` to global.scss

Comment: Thank you, I have moved `.swiper-pagination-bullet-active ` and CSS custom options to global.scss. But Nothing cahnged. How can I find style of moving?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mispoke. You'll want to move those Ionic specific styles into **variables.scss**, NOT **global.scss**